# How to estimate a probability distribution

Tags: regression, machine-learning, probability, curve-fitting, entropy

**Suppose I want to estimate a probability distribution, is it common practice to simply fit a function to a frequency histogram?**

So in my work, I am training a classifier, the performance of which is evaluated by its cross entropy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy). What I want to do, is to now predict what the cross entropy would be of some new test data. Rather than taking a point estimate though, I want a probability distribution over cross entropies, $p(h)$.

In order to estimate $p(h)$, what I have done is to find the cross entropies for all the training data for my classifier, and plotted a histogram. By inspection, this distribution looks rather like a Gamma distribution. Then, I used a least squares method to fit the parameters of a Gamma distribution to this histogram.

My question is: Is there a better way to estimate $p(h)$?

The above method seems a little naive to me, because:

1) I have only chosen the Gamma distribution by visual inspection, and there could be other functions that fit the data better

2) I need to discretize my cross entropies into a histogram, which inevitably results in loss of information

3) Cross entropy is a very principled, probabilistic concept, yet I am not using it at all in estimating $p(h)$ -- I am just treating it as a standard parameter fitting task

I would be very grateful for any help or hints. Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you heard of non-parametric density estimators like kernel estimators?

Comment: Yes I have just been looking into that. The problem is that I need the distribution to be differentiable, which is why I decided to chose an existing parameterized function rather than a non-parametric solution...

Comment: Wait, if you use a differentiable kernel like a Gaussian kernel, your estimate is differentiable as a sum of such kernels.